# Можно ли без нового объекта Connection открыть его снова если был вызван close()?

Tags: java, postgresql

Возможно ли не создавать новый инстанс:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        this.property.getUrlDB(),
        this.property.getUsername(),
        this.property.getPassword());

connection.close();
```

Если у меня он уже был создан но был вызван `close()` и метод `isClose()` возвращает `true`?

Comment: Нет. Зато можно **не** закрывать соединение сразу, а делать это только тогда, когда это действительно нужно. Если нужно часто открывать-закрывать соединение, то стоит использовать пул соединений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет. После вызова метода `close` толка от объекта `connection` уже нет. Для повторной установки соединения придётся воспользоваться метод `getConnection`.

Зато можно не открывать и закрывать соединение при каждым SQL-запросе, а держать соединение открытым на время обработки всего запроса к серверу. То есть открывать соединение в начале обработки запроса и закрывать в конце.

Если запросов к серверу идёт много, то стоит задуматься об использовании пула соединений. Например, [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/). В этом случае по-прежнему после вызова метода `close` пользоваться объектом `connection` будет нельзя, но зато запрос нового соединения и его закрытие будут приводить лишь к получению и возврату соединения в пул.